# str.contains not working when there is not a space between the word and special character

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, contains

I have a dataframe which includes the names of movie titles and TV Series.

From specific keywords I want to classify each row as Movie or Title according to these key words. However, due to brackets not having a space between the key words they are not being picked up by the `str.contains()` funtion and I need to do a workaround.

This is my dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

watched_df = pd.DataFrame([['Love Death Robots (Episode 1)'], 
                   ['James Bond'],
                   ['How I met your Mother (Avnsitt 3)'], 
                   ['random name'],
                   ['Random movie 3 Episode 8383893']], 
                  columns=['Title'])
watched_df.head()
```

To add the column that classifies the titles as TV series or Movies I have the following code.

```
watched_df["temporary_brackets_removed_title"] = watched_df['Title'].str.replace('(', '')
watched_df["Film_Type"] = np.where(watched_df.temporary_brackets_removed_title.astype(str).str.contains(pat = 'Episode | Avnsitt', case = False), 'Series', 'Movie')
watched_df = watched_df.drop('temporary_brackets_removed_title', 1)
watched_df.head()
```

Is there a simpler way to solve this without having to add and drop a column?

Maybe a `str.contains`-like function that does not look at a string being the exact same but just containing the given word? Similar to how in SQL you have the "Like" functionality?

Comment: Changing the pattern to `'Episode|Avnsitt'` do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.contains` and then `map` the results:

```py
watched_df['Film_Type'] = watched_df['Title'].str.contains(r'(?:Episode|Avnsitt)').map({True: 'Series', False: 'Movie'})
```

Output:

```py
>>> watched_df
                               Title Film_Type
0      Love Death Robots (Episode 1)    Series
1                         James Bond     Movie
2  How I met your Mother (Avnsitt 3)    Series
3                        random name     Movie
4     Random movie 3 Episode 8383893    Series
```

Comment: that definitely answers my question which I posted. However, after testing it I realized this doesn't word for when the words I am looking for are not attached to a bracket. Hence, column 4 where the title is "Random movie 3 Episode 8383893" it will be classified as a movie.

Comment: Updated. Try now, @Sebastien.

Comment: Works perfectly! thank you @user17242583.

Do I understand the code correctly that the "r'" stands for regex and the ?: means any character can be in front of the words of the contains function?

Comment: [What exactly do "u" and "r" string flags do, and what are raw string literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2081640/15497888) explains the `r` prefix on the string (it is often used with regex just because it makes escaping special characters easier) and [What is a non-capturing group in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/15497888) covers the `?:` part (though technically neither the raw-string nor the non-capturing group is strictly necessary here since `.str.contains('Episode|Avnsitt')` also works fine in this case) @SebastiantenBerge

Comment: Sorry @Sebastien - I didn't see that comment! As Henry linked, the `r` prefix stands for `raw` (so you don't have to escape backslashes) and is most commonly used with regexes, but the `r` is merely a coincidence. I added `?:` to avoid warnings - you can read more at the links Henry provided.